# jquery mobile swipe page conflict with slider control

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

I write below script to swipe page to next or prev page. but swipe page has conflict with swipe of slider control.

```
    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    $('img').on('dragstart', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
    function navnext(next) {
        //$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", next + ".html", {
        //    transition: "slide"
        //});
        $.mobile.changePage(next + ".html", { transition: "slide",reverse: false });
    }

    // Handler for navigating to the previous page
    function navprev(prev) {
        //$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", prev + ".html", {
        //    transition: "slide"
        //});
        $.mobile.changePage(prev + ".html", { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
    }

    // Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
    $(document).on("swipeleft", ".ui-page:not(.ui-slider)", function (event) {
        // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
        // attribute in the original markup.
        var next = $(this).jqmData("next");

        // Check if there is a next page and
        // swipes may also happen when the user highlights text, so ignore those.
        // We're only interested in swipes on the page.
        if (next && !$(this).hasClass("ui-slider")) {
            navnext(next);
        }
    });
    $(document).on("swiperight", ".ui-page:not(.ui-slider)", function (event) {
        var prev = $(this).jqmData("prev");

        if (prev && !$(this).hasClass("ui-slider")) {
            navprev(prev);
        }
    });

});
```

when I swipe on slider control ,I expect to change slider value , but page swiped instead of slider.
how can I solve this issue? how can I except some page's elements like slider from swiping page when user swipe on that element.

here is my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="page" id="relay" class="demo-page" data-title="Buenos Aires" data-dom-cache="true" data-prev="Index">

        <div id="mainContent" role="main" class="ui-content">
            <link href="css/smarthome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <script src="js/swipe.js"></script>

            <div id="header" data-role="header" data-id="header" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#Index" data-rel="external" data-transition="slide">
                                <img src="images/home.png" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#relay" class="ui-btn-active"><img src="images/relaynumber.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#sensor" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/sensor.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#setting" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/setting.png" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="relayDetail">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 padding30">
                    <div class="relayNumber">
                        <div class="relay"></div>
                        رله شماره 1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 padding30">
                    <div class="connected">
                        <div class="connect"></div>
                        جریان متصل است
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="relayName ui-field-contain">
                        <label class="label" for="relayname">نام رله:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="relayname" name="relayname" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="fuzeNumber ui-field-contain">
                        <label class="label" for="fuzenumber">شماره فیوز :</label>
                        <input type="number" id="fuzenumber" name="fuzenumber" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="border"></div>
                </div>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="parameters">
                    <legend>پارامترهای رله:</legend>
                    <div class="controlgroup">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="voltage">
                                <label class="label" for="topvoltage">حد بالای ولتاژ مجاز</label>
                                <input type="range" name="slider-1" value="230" min="0" max="250" data-highlight="true" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="voltage">
                                <label class="label" for="topvoltage"> حد پایین ولتاژ مجاز</label>
                                <input type="range" name="slider-2" value="210" min="0" max="250" data-highlight="true" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="voltage">
                                <label class="label" for="topvoltage">زمان تاخیر (ثانیه)</label>
                                <input type="range" name="slider-3" value="120" min="0" max="2000" data-highlight="true" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="protect">
                                <label class="label">
                                    درگاه محافظت :
                                </label>
                                <div class="relayDetail switch">
                                    <select data-role="slider">
                                        <option value="on">NC</option>
                                        <option value="off">NO</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="protect">
                                <label class="label">
                                    حفاظت :
                                </label>
                                <div class="relayDetail switch">
                                    <select data-role="slider">
                                        <option value="on">روشن</option>
                                        <option value="off">خاموش</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-carat-l"></a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-carat-r"></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQM seems to already handle this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yo343j73/  For me in Chrome, this fiddle works.

Comment: @ezanker : thank you for your answer. I have problem in small mobiles ,when user trying too change value of switchs and sliders using touch and swipe.

Comment: @ezanker : Please see my project in below link: http://94.183.165.133/smarthome/relay.html

Comment: @ezanker : I test project in mobile browsers , and this problem occure in some mobile browsers like Internet browser (default browser in android mobile and tablets)

Comment: See if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yo343j73/1/